# How to put data onto this Silverlight Timeline Control

Tags: silverlight, timeline

I've got the following problem: in our teams software you can navigate to a site (journal) which loads a individual history (journal entries). The history entries are currently shown in a grid. If you change the `SelectedItem`, additional data (details of the journal entry) is shown below the grid.

Now my team finds this [Silverlight Timeline Control](http://timeline.codeplex.com/) ([Silverlight Documentation](http://timeline.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20the%20Control%20from%20Silverlight&referringTitle=User%20Documentation)) pretty good for displaying historical data. I think this either.

My problem is that the only way to put data onto this timeline control is via XML files. That's not a viable solution for our project. Do you see a way to "bind" this to something like `ItemsSource`? The reason for this is that we have lots of "journals". And every journal you open shows a different history of journal entries. You also can add/edit/delete entries.

Comment: Did you ask the author of the control via his "contact me" on that page?

Comment: No I didn't. I thought maybe somebody used it already. Well, but it seems not much people used it, yet.

Comment: You might get lucky, either way I would be interested in the answer if/when you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through ResetEvents method. Timeline control calculates event positions, so it needs all events to calculate position of any. It loads them quickly, though, so 10k of events should not be a problem. Please use timeline forum http://timeline.codeplex.com/discussions for more help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question.
Is there another way to solve this? I'd prefer a solution without using codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add propery which calls reset events. This could be observable collection, subscribe to events of this collection and call reset events from there also. Makes sense?